# como cambio el color del background en mouseEnter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botón

Muy buenas noches a todos, resulta que tengo un problemita con los botones en visual C#, Resulta que hice una serie de botones que tienen una imagen, al pasar el mouse por encima este cambia a color gris y la imagen deja de verse, lo que visualmente se ve horrible, he intentado muchas cosas que no me han dado resultado, espero me puedan ayudar a resolver esta duda.

```
 <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Margin="11,47,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Width="63" 
             Click="Button_Click" 
             Height="43" 
             Grid.Column="1" 
             BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
             Foreground="{x:Null}" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter" 
             >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Imagen/anadir.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Button.Background>
```

Comment: Saludos. Le falto agregar el código con que hace ese efecto y le da el comportamiento que menciona; así mismo el código del botón.

Comment: Si por favor añade todo tu código que tenga que ver con el problema que describes, con el fin de poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: listo, ahí agregue el código de uno de los botones.